# How to resume python program skipping data files that have faulty line format?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to clean *.txt files from a folder. Some files do not have the right data format and python throws a traceback. how do I skip the improper files and resume with the others without having to remove it and re-run the program.

```
for filename in glob.glob('datafolder/*.txt'):
    inputfile = open(filename, 'r')
    npv = []
    for i, line in inputfile:
        npv.append(line[34:36])  # the site of fault
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataprep.py", line 51, in <module>
    npv.append(int(line[34:36]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I want to drop the current 'filename' and go ahead with the next 'filename'.

Comment: use exception handling

Answer (score 0):

Catch the `ValueError` and `break` the for-loop.

```
for filename in glob.glob('datafolder/*.txt'):
    inputfile = open(filename, 'r')
    npv = []
    for i, line in inputfile:
        try:
            npv.append(line[34:36])  # the site of fault
        except ValueError:
            break
```

Alternatively, you could `pass` the line and read other lines in the file if that makes sense to your task.